# Socket io, node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I will try to explain myself the best than I can!

I have a node.js server and I want to add socket.io. I manage to get it running on http but I'm having some problems running it on **https**.

**Server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');


var key = fs.readFileSync('mydomain.key');
var cert = fs.readFileSync( 'mydomain.crt' );

var options = {
key: key,
cert: cert
};

var https = require('https');
var io = require("socket.io")(https);
var cors = require('cors')

var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'domain');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();



server.on('error', function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    console.log("A user is connected");
    socket.on('add reserva',function(status){
    //io.sockets.emit('update reserva', status);
      add_reserva(status,function(res){
        if(res){io.sockets.emit('update reserva', status);} 
          else {io.sockets.emit('error');}
      });
    });
});

**And the client code:**

      $(document).ready(function(){
          var socket = io("https://151.236.63.10:443");
          $("#add_status").click(function(){
            socket.emit('add reserva',$("#comment").val());
          });
          socket.on('update reserva',function(msg){
            new Noty({
                type: 'success',
                layout: 'topRight',
                text: msg
            }).show();
          });
    });
});
```

In addicion, if there is something I could do better with the code, I would appreciate any advice

Comment: **https:// 151.236.63.10:443** An ip address cannot be ssl enabled. you need to define domain name.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say it's a VPS, I still need to define domain name?

Comment: var io = require("socket.io")(https); → I should replace it by → var io = require("socket.io")(server) [and so place it after the creation].  Btw I will place all stuff like 443 in a config file.

Comment: @cagliostro Thanks a lot man! It worked! "var io = require("socket.io")(server)"
How so place it in a config file?

Comment: @klnx just place your parameters in a config file (ex: config.js) and exports and object where you place all your var. Example: module.exports = {https:443} import it after in your server file, and instead of 443 you have config.https. Just cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll give you a rewriting to get something cleaner. Hope it helps.

```
const express = require express();
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('./config'); //--> config file 

var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('mydomain.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync( 'mydomain.crt' )
};

const secureServer = https.createServer(options,app).listen(config.portHTTPS);

const io = require('socket.io')(secureServer) // you can add options for socket here
```